# How to retrieve some data from database by servlet and display it in jsp?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

My home page has a dynamic content which I'd like to retrieve from database using servlet and display in index.jsp. The problem is I don't really know which method I'd have to implement to achieve this because there is no forms at the beggining so I can't use doGet or doPost. I'd like to consider my servlet as controller which provides model for jsp file.

Comment: Are you asking for a ready solution?

Comment: calling `index.jsf` without arguments is also calling `doGet()`, so implement it.

Comment: why dont you use Ajax to your servlet and update your jsp accordingly..?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Ajax.

Comment: do it with the proper way. use ajax, servlet and update your jsp using json. Don't say you don't know because google and this community is there to help you. see my answer below !

Comment: I'll do it the proper way. I'm just begginer in these technologies and  didn't know about Ajax. Thanks for suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the best approach is to send a jquery ajax call from your client to servlet (server side). Do your logic / database operations there and the output or object that you need to pass to the jsp page through JSON.

There are lot of examples on google and stackoverflow.

one of the easiest example can be found [here](http://www.journaldev.com/4742/jquery-ajax-servlet-jsp-web-application-integration-example-tutorial)

Learn it, really worth spending some time on this.

Comment: Thanks for advice. I am certainly going to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Create a simple web page that redirect automatically to servlet on page load and from there you can fetch data and send it to jsp.